# get trello comments using the api

Tags: trello

I am trying to get comments on a trello card since "the last time I checked". In the api, there is a since=lastView parameter https://trello.com/docs/api/card/

I tried to get the comments since last time I checked using this:

https://api.trello.com/1/cards/card_id/actions?filter=commentCard&since=lastView&key=my_key&token=my_token

But I always get all the comments in the card. Is there a way to get all the comments since the last check?

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you use `since=date` where `date` is the date of the newest action you got on your previous API call?

Comment: yes. If I use a date as parameter it works

Comment: did you find a solution?
I want to use the same for boards and I always get no results :/ I really don't like the api "documentation". Is it the last view via api or in general or...